# Mocking/patching an object attribute to test a method

Tags: python, python-3.x, mocking, pytest, patch

I'm testing my code with pytest and am trying to figure out the most direct way to test one of my class' methods.

I have a class like:

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self, stuff):
     ...
    ..
    ..
    def _method_of_interest(self, list1, list2):
        
        ..some logic that depends on list1, list2, and self.relevant_info
  
        return output
```

I'd like to test the method `_method_of_interest` as a function of some list1, list2, and self.relevant_info combinations. I'd prefer to not have to instantiate a real object of MyClass because elsewhere in the logic chain there's some time-consuming computations and I can't easily create objects which have the full range of `self.relevant_info` values I'd like to test.

What is the cleanest way for me to test the output of this method, with varying list1, list2, and self.relevant_info values?

For concreteness, we can pretend that `_method_of_interest` is something like:

```
def _method_of_interest(list1, list2):
    return list1 + list2 + list(self.relevant_info)
```

where self.relevant_info is a python set() object.

Any pointers? There's a lot on mocking, patching, etc. online but the examples all look more complicated than my case and the variety of ways one can solve the problem is making me uncertain which way would be the cleanest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to test a method in complete isolation from the rest of the class, you can always pass a mock `self`:

```
# code under test
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self):
        raise NotImplementedError  # don't instantiate me!

    def _method_of_interest(self, list1, list2):
        return list1 + list2 + list(self.relevant_info)


# test
from unittest.mock import Mock

def test_method_of_interest():
    assert MyClass._method_of_interest(
        Mock(relevant_info=[3]), [1], [2]
    ) == [1, 2, 3]
```

If you run the test, you'll see that it passes, and that `MyClass` is never instantiated.

Comment: Great, that'll work for me. Thanks!

Comment: Sam, can you point me towards a solution in the event that my `_method_of_interest` now not only requires `self.relevant_info` but also requires the calling of another method `_another_method(self, listA)` which only requires listA and `relevant_info`?

Comment: I suppose in this case I actually want more of my class (access to its methods), but just having the ability to customize the `relevant_info` attribute.

Comment: I crated a new question for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71473223/mocking-patching-an-object-attribute-to-test-a-method-also-need-access-to-other

Comment: You could potentially adjust your mocked `self` to wrap `_another_method`.  At some point, though, you should be taking a hard look at the design of the rest of your class -- maybe there should be a way to short-circuit some of those expensive logic chains in the class itself rather than having to construct elaborate mocks to avoid them in your tests?

Comment: To elaborate further -- maybe this class should be split in two (in between the resource-intensive stuff you want to mock out and the less intense stuff you want to test independently of it), so that you can test each class more-or-less atomically without having to stub out individual methods.

Comment: You're probably right here, @Samwise. I think just separating out the logic a bit more and taking anything difficult of out of my class constructor is probably the way to go.