# Mocking/patching an object attribute to test a method (also need access to other class methods)

Tags: python, python-3.x, mocking, pytest, patch

I have a method of a class I'd like to test with pytest, such as the method `_method_of_interest` below.

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self, stuff):
     ...
    ..
    ..
    def _method_of_interest(self, list1, list2):
        """
        some logic that depends on list1, list2, and self.relevant_info
        Also calls self._helper_method(list)
        """
        output = list1 + list2 + self._helper_method(list2) + self.relevant_info

  
        return output 

    def _helper_method(self, lista):
        """
        Helper method depends on lista and self.relevant_info
        """
        
        return lista + self.relevant_info
```

I'd like to be able to test `_method_of_interest` with different values of list1, list2, and self.relevant_info. So I mostly need to be able to specify a value for `self.relevant_info`. What is the cleanest way to do this with Python?

Comment: That depends; where does `self.relevant_info` come from? It could be as simple as setting `object.relevant_info = ...` before calling `object._method_of_interest(testlist1, testlist2)`.

Comment: More likely, unless the value comes from some outside resource that you need to stub out, you want to simply let it get set the way it does in practice.

Comment: @chepner, maybe it's as simple as that (just setting the attribute manually). The value is a simple set object, but it's actual computation is dependent upon me having a certain complex PDF document in front of me. I have a lot more cases I'd like to test than real-life documents that are ready for using in tests.

Comment: Somewhere in your code, you should factor out the parsing of the PDF file so the you can provide the expected result of that parsing as an object to whatever function needs it. Then you can "pretend" the PDF was parsed and still test your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest approach would be to use the builtin [unittest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html) framework.

Define multiple test cases. In each, you create a new MyClass object with the `stuff` defined for that test. Then you compare the output of my_class._method_of_interest to some predefined expected output (with the assertEqual method of unittest.TestCase). Of course, you can do multiple test, for multiple different lists 1&2.

EDIT:
If you can't set `relevant_info` through the constructor itself then you can always manually adjust it. Class attributes are not protected in python, no-one can stop you from doing:

```
my_class = MyClass(unrelevant_info)
my_class.relevant_info = relevant_info
```

But if you need to do it then there is something fishy going on in the code.